# Does UWSGI influence LDAPS Requests from an underlying Django app?

Tags: python, django, active-directory, uwsgi, python-ldap

I have plugged in this class as an authentication backend in django

```
class ActiveDirectoryBackend(object):

    logger = Messenger.infrastructure

    @classmethod
    def authenticate(cls, username=None, password=None):

        try:
            bind_dn = "%s@%s" % (username, settings.AD_DNS_NAME)

            try:
                cls.logger.debug('Initializing: %s' % settings.AD_LDAP_URL)
                l = ldap.initialize(settings.AD_LDAP_URL)
                l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
                l.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
                cls.logger.debug('Binding user %s' % bind_dn)
                l.simple_bind_s(bind_dn, password)
                result = l.search_ext_s(settings.AD_SEARCH_DN, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                                        "sAMAccountName=%s" % username, settings.AD_SEARCH_FIELDS)[0][1]
                email = result.get('mail', (None,))[0]
            except ldap.SERVER_DOWN, ex:
                cls.logger.warning('LDAP-Sever Down (%s)' % ex.message)
                raise PermissionDenied
            except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
                cls.logger.warning('LDAP-Server: Rejected login for user %s due to invalid credentials' % username)
                raise PermissionDenied

            cls.logger.debug('User %s was successfully authorized.' % username)

            l.unbind_s()

        except Exception:
            raise PermissionDenied

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            cls.logger.debug('User %s found for email %s ' % (user.username, email))

        except ObjectDoesNotExist, ex:
            cls.logger.debug('User for email %s could not be found.' % email)
            raise PermissionDenied

        return user
```

The whole thing is running under Apache + uWSGI.
When I run Django standalone (manage.py runserver) everything works fine with LDAP and LDAPS.

But when running it under uWSGI with LDAPS it always throws "Server Down".
LDAP (w/o 's') works.
Using tcpdump I can see packets going in both directions between AD and my server.

How does uWSGI influence the LDAPS communication between python-ldap or the underlying libraries and the Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By playing around with the options on commandline ldapsearch a colleague and me found out what resolves the problem - but not what exactly caused the problem in the first place.

By explicitly setting the HOST option, we got it to work.

In python it looks like this:

```
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_HOST_NAME, settings.AD_DNS_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

uWSGI does some ["clever" tricks](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html) by default when it spawns its workers.

> uWSGI tries to (ab)use the Copy On Write semantics of the fork() call
>   whenever possible. By default it will fork after having loaded your
>   applications to share as much of their memory as possible. If this
>   behavior is undesirable for some reason, use the lazy-apps option.
>   This will instruct uWSGI to load the applications after each worker’s
>   fork().

In my experience this does effect some libraries (like FreeTDS). Try the mentioned `lazy-apps` option.